# What should I be indexing? Usernames or User IDs?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, create-table

I have a fairly simple table *(forgive errors / stupidity, I'm still learning. Written for MySQL)*:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `userdata` (
    `userid`    UNSIGNED int(18446744073709551615) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `username`  char(255) NOT NULL,
    `password`  char(255) NOT NULL,
    `salt`      char(255) NOT NULL,
    `email`     char(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(`userid`)
);
```

I've read that adding an index improves the performance of a query, as it doesn't need to look through the entire database. Instead, it will look through the index and match data (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've found out how to create an index well enough, but not what I should be indexing.
Should I have my index on usernames? Email addresses, user ID, or some field I've yet to add?

Comment: That depends upon which types of queries you're be running on the table.  Will you be searching it by name or ID or both, for example?

Comment: Most likely by name for searches (such as the search tool here, or ones found on forums), and ID internally.     I'm willing to use whatever is fastest though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**you should ONLY create an index based on you actual usage of the column**

usage in a **WHERE**:
if you never have `WHERE username='xyz'`, the no index is needed
if you have many of these, then add an index

usage in a **JOIN**:
if you never have any `JOIN xxxx ON x.userid=u.userid`, then no index is needed
if you have many of these, then add an index

Comment: So then if I have my userid field set as the primary key, indexing it manually is useless?

Comment: I couldn't quickly find a link to an article explaining it, but this may help: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

Comment: @Alexander. Yes, it will most probably be redundant since the db will need to index it anyway to check efficiently that there are no duplicated pks

Answer (score 6):

You should have an index on pretty much any column that you're doing keyed lookups on.  Is something going to do a `where userid = ?` in one of your queries?  Then index on `userid`.  Are you going to be doing lookups on `username`?  Then index on username.  What about on `password`?  Probably not, so don't bother.

Comment: Primary keys already automatically get "indexed".  Just make the column type "serial" and away you go.

Answer (score 3):

What fields will you be searching on? Those should be your first candidates for indexes. Also index any columns that will become foreign keys in other tables (`userid` seems like a likely candidate).

Comment: Any field relevant to the users search (excluding password and salt).

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to consider is whether this field will often be used for **searching and filtering** through records. If yes, index it. Other answers addressed that well.

However, keep in mind that indexes **add some overhead** to insert and update operations. If a field is updated constantly, but rarely used in search clauses, you may be disappointed to find out that the index is actually slowing you down instead of improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

Primay ID shoud go to the userid.
It's very helpful in now and in the long run.